# AngularJs execute a function after view render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in Angularjs,
I am try to write a function,that can automatically run after ng-repeat render complete.
this is a function I found online

```
angular('myController',['myDirective']).controller([
'$scope',
'myService',
function($scope,myService){
    $scope.List = {};
    var list = myService.get({},
        function Success(){
            $scope.List = list;
        }
    );
]};


angular('myDirective',[]).directive('myList',
['$timeout',
function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {//make sure the view is rendered
                $timeout(fn.ListIsReady, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Is this the only way to make sure fn.ListIsReady will be execute after view render?
I'll ask this because the function 'mydirective.link' will be executed every time when there is a item be rendered.I think that's not smart.

Comment: Really? But I tried to trace the executing times,it trace the number that is the same as the list size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a `$watchCollection` to monitor when the list changes, and then use `$timeout` to execute a function after the render phase:

```
angular('myController',['myDirective']).controller(['$scope', '$timeout','myService',
function($scope,$timeout, myService){
    $scope.List = {};
    var list = myService.get({},
        function Success(){
            $scope.List = list;
        }
    );
    $scope.$watchCollection('List', function(newList) {
        if (newList)
            $timeout(fn.ListIsReady);
    });
]};
```